# Reading multiline ints using scanf() in C form standard input

Tags: c, arrays, input, int, multiline

5

3 2 3 1 2

input looks like this

1. First line is an int that tells how many ints I will get in the second line of input (the number is <=200).
2. Second line ints should be fed into an array of type int.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: This looks like requirements for a program you want, not like an actual, specific programming question. But I do not even get the requirements. Reasing ints into an array cannot be the only thing the program is supposed to do. Except if it is a pure homework assignment, which only intends to teach you about reading and about arrays. If you really have no idea about how to do it you should study the text book for your course. If that does not help find a tutorial, if that is too advanced, start with a HelloWorld. Maybe asking your teacher is helpful, too. For help here, take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the first line and after you know how many entries you will have in the second line you could do a for like this:

```
char template[32];

memset(template, 0x00, sizeof(template));

for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
    strcat(template, "%d");
```

And after that you could use the array as template for sscanf:

```
int num[200];

sscanf(line2, template, &num[0], &num[1], &num[2],...);
```

You could put all the array inside the sscanf, also if there are less value, because the end of the string "line2" is treated as an end-of-file condition.